# iAd appears in simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, iad

When I run my application I can see my iAd in the simulator, that is pre-filled with "Test Advertisement"

However, when I run the application on my device, the iAd area is blank, with no pre-filled ad.

Why is this?

My iAd is in a UITableViewCell:

```
#import "iAdCell.h"


@implementation iAdCell
@synthesize adView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
        adView.delegate=self;
        [self.contentView addSubview:adView];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [adView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Supply more information. Are you hiding the ad when an error occurs as per Apple's recommendations? If so, do you have network connectivity? And even then, it could take several seconds to show up, I've even had to wait longer for the test ad to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after questioner added more information:

Apple will reject your application if an iAd is within a table cell. iAds are required to be in a static position on the page, and not in any kind of scroll view (this includes table views). This is because iAds pay by impression as well as by click, so having an iAd in a table view cell will cause it to be reloaded whenever it scrolls off and on screen again, which could be many times. This would seem like "click-fraud" or similar behaviour. Apple will not allow this.

---

Probably because your request is failing. Put a breakpoint or some logging into the failure delegate message that is sent when requests fail and you will be able to see if it is getting called.

iAd requests can fail for a number of reasons, including iAds not being available in your country, there not being enough inventory to fulfil a request, the ad has already been shown once this session, etc.

It's possible that is displays on the Simulator because the Simulator doesn't really have any concept of its location (eg, Maps always shows your location as Apple's HQ in Cupertino).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what solved the problem for me was simply to delete the app from your device and reinstall from XCode.