# iAds showing in Simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, iad

I have incorporated iAds into a new version of my iOS program.  Everything seems to be working great in the simulator, with test iAds being loaded and the ADAdBanner being moved up into the screen when ad material comes in.

When I run the program on my device, however, no test ads get loaded.

Is this normal behavior, or should I have gotten test ads on my device as well?   I am thinking maybe this is normal but that ads will come through once it is published to Apple.

Thanks

Comment: hello. What is your OS simulator && device ? what's your xCode version ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iAd appears in simulator but not on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711637/iad-appears-in-simulator-but-not-on-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable iAds on your binary in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if that doesn't work, delete the app from your device and reinstall.

Comment: Are you going to post this answer to every iAd question on stack overflow? ;-)

Comment: on every one that has this problem. i was looking for quite a while and never found this answer. so i thought i'd search out the people with the same problem for posterity. :)

Comment: Ok, cool. You'd just filled up my SO frontpage and I was getting worried!